# homemade cleaner for basic drip coffee maker

Tags: cleaning

Is it possible to create a cleaning agent to use on a basic drip coffee maker using household items? If so, what ingredients are needed and in what ratios?

I am mostly concerned with cleaning the insides that I believe are made from plastic. The carafe I can clean separately. I know that there are products on the market, but I am interested in homemade solutions.

Comment: Not sure if this on topic as product recommendations usually aren't on SO.

Comment: I don't want a product recommendation, I want the opposite, the best combinations of ingredients to make a home made cleaner instead of a product. If coffee cleaner info doesn't belong though that's fine.

Comment: My apologies I skipped the homemade part, in that case I think this is fine

Comment: Are the insides removable?

Comment: No, it is a pretty typical model with a reservoir to hold the water and all the parts to move and heat the water encapsulated in plastic. In the past I have run a combination of water in vinegar through it, just wasn't sure if that was best

Comment: hopefully my edit makes the question less subjective

Comment: Isn't this more like off-topic?

Comment: But no, I'll not vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordinary white vinegar works just fine, but the smell bothers some people. If so, use citric acid. You can either pick some up at your local grocer, or [order it by the pound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008AYJ3HY). I use about a tablespoon to a quart for descaling. It's gentle, has little or no odor (you may smell gasses released by the dissolved scale however), and safe unless you get it in your eyes.